# Android widget change update time

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using this code to schedule my widget

```
// Timer
Timer timer = new Timer();
// Schedule time
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 60000);

private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
    // RemoveViews
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    // AppWidgetManager
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    // ComponentName
    ComponentName thisWidget;

    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.main);
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WMTWidget.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code to update textview
    }
}
```

This updates a textview every minute which works fine

I'm wondering if it's possible to change this after the first run ?
it should update the textview the first time after 1 minute and then every 15 minutes

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Try This It may work**

// Timer

```
int time=1; //Defined it  global

Timer timer = new Timer();
// Schedule time

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), time, 60000);

     time=15; //update time for 15 minutes Now it will take 15 minute interval

private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
    // RemoveViews
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    // AppWidgetManager
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    // ComponentName
    ComponentName thisWidget;

    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {

        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.main);
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WMTWidget.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code to update textview
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I've already tried something similar to this, problem is that he only passes once through the "onUpdate" part so the time can only be set once ...